# Citing a Wikipedia article

Tags: wikipedia

Is there an automatic way to create an academic citation or a BibTeX record from a Wikipedia article? (Similar to the "cite" link in StackExchange.)

Comment: SE has a “cite” link? I certainly can't find anything like that. Also, have you tried clicking on the “Cite this page” link in the sidebar?

Comment: @svick  In some SE sites, such as Math.SE and CSTheory.SE, when you click "share", there is a "cite" link. Apparently this is not relevant to all SE sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sidebar, under *Tools*, is a link to *Cite this page*. Click this link. (You can also get there by going to http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ACite and entering the name of the page you want.)

[image: screen shot]

Under the warning about using tertiary sources in your academic papers and a general disclaimer that it is a community-edited resource is a set of citations. Currently, the supported formats are:

- APA Style
- MLA Style
- MHRA Style
- Chicago Style
- CBE/CSE Style
- Bluebook: Harvard JOLT Style
- AMA Style
- BibTeX entry (both with and without the use of LaTeX package url)
- Wiki style (for use on Wikipedia talk pages)

When you click the link it specifically references the most recent revision of the article. If you want to cite an earlier version you'll need to go to the article's history.